# R: how to write into dataframe column with function

Tags: r

i have issue with my function, i would like to or write directly into my dataframe column or to write in list with name but nothing is working.

```
t.peaks <- function(X, i, n){

file_name <- paste("/work/gad/shared/analyse/STR/Marine/analysis/output/annotation/R_plots/", strsplit(n, "[.]")[[1]][4],"_", strsplit(n, "[.]")[[1]][5], "_", i, ".png", sep="")
print(i)
d <- density(as.numeric(as.matrix(X)), na.rm=T)
peaks <- NULL
for (i in 2:(length(d$y)-1)) {
  if (d$y[i-1] >= d$y[i] & d$y[i] <= d$y[i+1]) {
    peaks <- cbind(peaks, c(d$x[i], d$y[i]))
  }}

if (is.null(peaks)){

return(NULL)
}


if (ncol(peaks) > 1) {

png(file=file_name)
plot(d, main=n,cex.main=0.7)
dev.off()
print(peaks[,-1][1])
return(peaks[,-1][1])

}

}

names <- rownames(baseM.num.fltr_20)
mylist <- sapply(names,function(x) NULL)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(baseM.num.fltr_20))) mylist[i] <- t.peaks(baseM.num.fltr_20[i,],i, names[[i]])
```

with this function i'm only trying to write one number into mylist at specific index given by the loop. But i have two problems, 1) the number of rows is not the same before and after.
before :

```
> length(mylist)
[1] 48374
```

after:

```
> length(mylist)
[1] 48373
```

and the names i gave to my rows on mylist just disappered at the end of the list but not at the beginning ??

```
> head(mylist)
$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr8.(137369709, 137370709).KHDRBS3.intergenic..`
[1] 7.805517

$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr10.(76061607, 76062607).ADK.intronic..,Hypermethioninemia due to adenosine kinase deficiency, 614300 (3)`
[1] 7.805517

$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr1.(119840796, 119841796).WARS2-AS1.intergenic..`
NULL

$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr2.(159751585, 159752585).DAPL1.intergenic..`
NULL

$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr2.(178437968, 178438968).TTC30B.intergenic..`
NULL

$`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr2.(191921979, 191922979).STAT4.intronic..,{Systemic lupus erythematosus, susceptibility to, 11}, 612253 (3)`
NULL
```

and at the end :

```
[[48302]]
[1] 8.67151

[[48303]]
NULL

[[48304]]
NULL

[[48305]]
[1] 8.59759

[[48306]]
[1] 8.349983

[[48307]]
NULL

[[48308]]
NULL

[[48309]]
[1] 10.5404

[[48310]]
NULL

[[48311]]
[1] 5.444532
```

then i trie to write directly into baseM.num.fltr_20$value with the same function but i just get NULL at the end.
i can't understand what is wrong with my function.
i'm dealing with big table, 48374 rows and 650 columns.

my data look like that :

```
    dijen003
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr12.(32817349, 32818349).FGD4.intergenic..,Charcot-Marie-Tooth disease, type 4H, 609311 (3)                     NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr4.(150402584, 150403584).IQCM.intronic..                                                                       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr8.(137369709, 137370709).KHDRBS3.intergenic..                                                                  NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr10.(76061607, 76062607).ADK.intronic..,Hypermethioninemia due to adenosine kinase deficiency, 614300 (3)       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr8.(75631790, 75632790).MIR2052HG.ncRNA_intronic..                                                              NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr1.(119840796, 119841796).WARS2-AS1.intergenic..                                                                NA
                                                                                                                                 dijen004
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr12.(32817349, 32818349).FGD4.intergenic..,Charcot-Marie-Tooth disease, type 4H, 609311 (3)                     NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr4.(150402584, 150403584).IQCM.intronic..                                                                       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr8.(137369709, 137370709).KHDRBS3.intergenic..                                                                  NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr10.(76061607, 76062607).ADK.intronic..,Hypermethioninemia due to adenosine kinase deficiency, 614300 (3)       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr8.(75631790, 75632790).MIR2052HG.ncRNA_intronic..                                                              NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr1.(119840796, 119841796).WARS2-AS1.intergenic..                                                                NA
                                                                                                                                 dijen005
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr12.(32817349, 32818349).FGD4.intergenic..,Charcot-Marie-Tooth disease, type 4H, 609311 (3)                     NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr4.(150402584, 150403584).IQCM.intronic..                                                                       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr8.(137369709, 137370709).KHDRBS3.intergenic..                                                                  NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr10.(76061607, 76062607).ADK.intronic..,Hypermethioninemia due to adenosine kinase deficiency, 614300 (3)       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr8.(75631790, 75632790).MIR2052HG.ncRNA_intronic..                                                              NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr1.(119840796, 119841796).WARS2-AS1.intergenic..                                                                NA
                                                                                                                                 dijen006
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr12.(32817349, 32818349).FGD4.intergenic..,Charcot-Marie-Tooth disease, type 4H, 609311 (3)                     NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr4.(150402584, 150403584).IQCM.intronic..                                                                       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr8.(137369709, 137370709).KHDRBS3.intergenic..                                                                  NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC.chr10.(76061607, 76062607).ADK.intronic..,Hypermethioninemia due to adenosine kinase deficiency, 614300 (3)       NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr8.(75631790, 75632790).MIR2052HG.ncRNA_intronic..                                                              NA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG.chr1.(119840796, 119841796).WARS2-AS1.intergenic..                                                                NA
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: Please type `dput(head(baseM.num.fltr_20))` and post the output into your question. Your data as shown above is too hard to use.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).